# Dropdown Selection in Python Selenium with ng-model

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

My web page has a following attribute for select box and I wish to select the first option as **All Category**

```
<select ng-model="abc" ng-change="abc(abc)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty" style="">
                <option disabled="" value="" selected="selected">Select a category...</option>
                <option value="All Category">All Category</option>
```

Is the anyway I can find element by ng-model="abc" or class and select the option "All category" from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath for finding the element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='All Category']")
```

You can read more about xpath on [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

The desired elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched.ng-not-empty[ng-model='abc']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched.ng-not-empty[ng-model='abc'] option[value='All Category']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty' and @ng-model='abc']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty' and @ng-model='abc']//option[@value='All Category']"))).click()
  ```